# Set X/Y axis in imshow in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I think my problem is probably easy to solve, however I do not manage to set my X/Y axis using imshow in Python.

For example, I have an image of size 61*61 and I want the axis to range from -30 to 30 and not from 0 to 61 as it is the case by default.

Hope someone could help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `extent=` keyword argument to [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow).

```
plt.imshow(image, extent=(-30,30,-30,30)) # (left, right, bottom, top)
```

Comment: Yes I just found this argument! Thanks!